# How to uninstall linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

I was building linux kernel from git master for ubuntu all day, I was not able to build packages, so I just ran `sudo make module_install install`. How to remove it? Makefile doesn't provide `make uninstall` and `make remove` actions. Which directories should I purge?